# Sending data over HTTP using GET for services running over different ports

Tags: javascript, python, flask-restful

I am trying to transfer some data from one of the server running on port 5000 to the server running on port 2000. I need to GET the data first in port 5000 from some link, let's say: http://abc@xyz.com:password@localhost:5000/api/data (where abc@xyz.com:password is the admin user who has permissions to read the data); and then send this data to other server running on port 2000.

I have already tried using this script but it's returning null, but when I open http://abc@xyz.com:password@localhost:5000/api/data directly, it returns me the data :

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "http://abc@xyz.com:password@localhost:5000/api/data";
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.onload = function(e) {
        var status = xhr.status;
        console.log("Data is " + xhr.responseText);
    }
    xhr.send(null);
```

The application running on port 5000 is build on Flask framework, and data I am sending to (port 2000) is build using HTML with javascript.

Is that I am doing it wrong, or will this method not work?

Comment: maybe it's miunderstanding the two `@` in he url. Have you tried to `encodeURIComponent()` the actual username and the password? If it is a restriction on ajax requests, then there should be some comment on that in the console.

Comment: And `localhost` is kind of an exception/special domain. Have you tried to run this on a different domain? Like hosting that in a VM, or on a Server that supports domain names; not sure wether it could be sufficient to just forward a domain name by your local hosts file, sth. like `local.net`

Comment: @Thomas yes I tried encoding the url, using encodeURIComponent(). And also using ngrok to create tunneling between the servers. But both didn't work for me.

Comment: @Thomas Is that it has to be done using Socket Programming or is it that it can be done directly too?

Comment: What do the dev-tools tell you about the attempted ajax-connection? There has to be some info in the network-tab or the console about what's going on there.